# C++ Optional<Child Class pointer> Map as function argument

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

can I use `Optional<Parent Class pointer> Map` as function parameter while passing `Optional<Child Class pointer> Map` as argument?

For example, I have two classes and a map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <optional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
       virtual void f() = 0;
}; //abstract class

class B : public A {
    public:
       void f() override {
           std::cout <<"override only" << std::endl;
       }
};

void testFunction(std::map<int, std::optional<std::shared_ptr<B>>>) {
    std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::optional<std::shared_ptr<A>>> map;
    testFunction(map);
    return 0;
}
```

code link:
When I want to pass map to testFunction, compiler throws "no conversion" error.

```
main.cpp:27:18: error: could not convert ‘map’ from ‘map<[...],optional>>’ to ‘map<[...],optional>>’
```

Is it because of the Optional or Map? (I think it's map, because map<int, Parent Class> doesn't work neither.

Is there a way to pass a map with optional of child class pointer?

Thanks!

=======

Or let's talk about a simpler version, we only have pointer in the map, is there a way to achieve below codes:

```
void testFunction(std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<B>>) {
    std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>> map;
    testFunction(map);
}
```

Comment: A side note: why do you need an `std::optional` of a `std::shared_ptr` ? the `shared_ptr` by itself can be empty (nullptr), similarly to what you achieve with `a std::optional`.

Comment: Anyway: `std::map ... std::shared_ptr<A>>>` cannot be converted to `std::map ... std::shared_ptr<B>>>` (even if the `A`s are actually `B`s). These are different types.

Comment: @wohlstad, yeah, even I use the pointer in the map, it doesn't work, because of they are two different maps, and not convertible.

Comment: A `std::shared_ptr<A>` may or may not refer to an object of type `B` - the "may not" part is why an implicit conversion is not allowed

Comment: @UnholySheep But if the function parameter is Map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>>(```e.g. void testFunction(std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>>)```), and I pass in Map<int, std::shared_ptr<B>>, it throws the similar exception. But ```std::shared_ptr<B>``` does refer to an objet of type A, right?

Comment: But a map containing those is not a child of a map containing the others. C++ simply doesn't work the way you think it works.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik yeah, I think that's the reason. But is there a way for workaround? Do I need to build a new map and cast the object B to object A(or cast A to B)?

Comment: This is correct, that is the only thing that can be done: to create a new map. There are no workarounds.

Comment: even if you write `std::shared_ptr<A>` you're still copying it.

Comment: As @wohlstad noticed, `shared_ptr` is already nullable. Moreover, it is polymorphic, and you may work with `shared_ptr<A>` whenever you have a pointer to B. Instead of looking for a workaround you sould restate the problem.

Comment: *"Or let's talk about a simpler version"* -- this is good, but even better would be re-writing the question so that the more complex version never appears. No one has answered yet, so a complete revision of the question is still fair game.

Comment: When you do your revision, please don't capitalize things that are not capitalized. Identifiers are case-sensitive; the names `Map` and `map` are not the same.